# Add basic text below Calendar without using Content Editor Web Part in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I'm trying to add a basic link below my Calendar page without using any web parts. I noticed that when adding another web part to the Calendar page, the view dropdown in the browse tab ribbon UI disappears. I'd like to keep the view options and add a link below the calendar. Any methods to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I found the solution.](http://vintentou.wordpress.com/2010/08/03/missing-dropdown-menu-for-choosing-of-views/)

Go to the list view .aspx file and go to line 12 which has

```
<SharePoint:ListTitleViewSelectorMenu AlignToParent="true" id="LTViewSelectorMenu" runat="server" />
```

Replace with this code

```
<SPAN id=onetidPageTitleSeparator><SPAN><SPAN style="POSITION: relative; WIDTH: 11px; DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 11px; OVERFLOW: hidden"><IMG style="POSITION: absolute; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; TOP: -585px !important; LEFT: 0px !important" alt=: src="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"></SPAN></SPAN></SPAN>
<SharePoint:ViewSelectorMenu ID="viewSelectorMenu1" runat="server" />
```

It should show the view dropdown even with a content editor web part.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution can be that you could use delegate control to render javascript on the Calendar page.

You could either use ClientScriptManager to register it or can use Controls also

Ex:

```
ClientScriptManager clientScript = this.Page.ClientScript;
clientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "key", "script");
```

or

```
Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"script");
```

Use the following js script to add the link.

```
$('#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView').append("<div><a href=''>your link</a></div>");
```

Comment: Would this require Visual Studios? I only have designer access and SharePoint Designer to work with. If not, would I go to "default view".aspx of the Calendar to add the script?

Comment: yes...its requires VS..but u are correct u can do it using designer.

Comment: Could you give me an example of injecting the Controls.Add in the "view".aspx? Would it be right after the Calendar webpart </WebPartPages:ListViewWebPart>? Would I use a <p>Controls...</p>? How would I reference the JS?

Comment: http://dcsharepointchick.blogspot.in/2012/10/how-to-create-sharepoint-delegate.html
have a look at this.

Comment: But it looks like to implement a Delegate Control, I need Visual Studios which I don't have/know how to use. Is there no way to just slap on a link in a specific calendar web part at the bottom?

Comment: man....U didn't get me...If u want through Designer ..edit the page and add the script part on the page. I think I got u confused with VS and designer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11502/discussion-between-pushpendra-and-nuk11888)

Comment: i need 20 points to chat...

Comment: okay....no problems...are u still facing difficulty ?

Comment: Yes, I don't see how I can add the script into .aspx.. i've been searching online and came up to this page. http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/08/sharepoint-2010-missing-view-dropdown.html but he doesn't explain how he accomplished it

Comment: If I add the link or instructions, SharePoint Designer automatically creates a custom web part which disables the view dropdown

Comment: found a solution

Answer (score 0):

You could have a [Custom Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460194%28v=office.14%29.aspx) that has a ScriptSrc or ScriptBlock that would run on every page in the SPWeb.  The script could look at the URL and decide to add DOM elements for only specific pages.  With this approach your javascript would have to know how to find the page(s) based on the URL (pretty easy) and would have to know the markup well enough on those pages to know where to add DOM elements.

Comment: Would I upload a script file to SharePoint and reference it in the .aspx view of the calendar?

Comment: The script must go in layouts (ScriptSrc) or be inline in the CustomAction xml (ScriptBlock).  Here is a blog that describes this a little: http://www.spdeveloper.co.in/tipsntricks/pages/referencing-js-files-using-custom-action.aspx